# Can I roll non-Treasure Room items on regular pedestals on the Chest?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I just need to collect a couple of items to get Platinum God. One is a Secret Room item (Black Lotus) and one is an Angel Room item (Sacred Heart). Importantly, neither is in the Treasure Room item pool. The wiki page about [Special Items](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Special_Item) says

> Since the reroll chance rapidly increases to a high percentage, seeing 3-4 special items can be enough to make **some special items that aren't in Treasure Room Pool** (Godhead, Sacred Heart, Brimstone,..) require hundreds of D6 rolls before appearing.
>
> - **However, these special items will always appear** after a certain number of rerolls, even if the Treasure Room Pool was emptied and Breakfast starts to appear. In these situations, infinite D6 uses and patience are required.

Since the chests on the Chest level turn into pedestals with Treasure Room items, this makes me think that I can reroll those pedestals to the items I am looking for. However, I have been rolling in the Chest starting room for a long time and I haven't gotten any non-Treasure Room items, even non-special ones. So, can I reroll those pedestals to Secret Room or Angel Room items?

Comment: You have to reroll items in the same item pool. Sacred Heart is one of the hardest item to find imho (due to the Angel Room), it took me several hours on the previous game. Black Lotus it's not so rare, I've already found it twice (the second one with a reroll).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
There's no way to "upgrade" from generic treasure item pool to angel or satan items via exhaustion. The quoted passage refers to rerolling i.e. in an Angel Room.

Since the Angel Room Items are replaced with Items from the treasure item pool when exhausted, the special-reroll-condition will likely bring lots of normal Treasure Items before showing the Sacred Heart.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate. It makes sense that that's what the quote meant, though.